# Expected value of a sample variance

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm studying pattern recognition and now I'm learning about maximum likelihood. I came a cross with the expected value of the sample variance, which I don't understand where the formulation comes from...

$$\hat{\sigma}^2_{ML} = \displaystyle\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}(x_k-\hat{\mu})^2$$

$$E(\hat{\sigma}^2_{ML}) = \displaystyle\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}E[(x_k-\hat{\mu})^2] = \displaystyle\frac{N-1}{N}\sigma^2$$

Why is the latter part true? $\hat{\sigma}^2_{ML}$ is the maximum likelihood estimator of the variance, $\hat{\mu}$ is the mean value of the sample $x_1, ..., x_N$ and $\sigma^2$ is the true variance.

This is confusing, because I would presume that $E[(x_k-\hat{\mu})^2] = \sigma^2$ by definition of the variance in which case the formula would be:

$$E(\hat{\sigma}^2_{ML}) = \displaystyle\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}E[(x_k-\hat{\mu})^2] = \displaystyle\frac{N*\sigma^2}{N} = \sigma^2$$

What am I missing here :) Thank you for helping out!

Comment: The best way to resolve your perplexity is to compute $E[(x_k-\hat\mu)^2]$ and see that it is not $\sigma^2$ but $\frac{N-1}N\sigma^2$. (Note that, here, $\hat\mu$ is the *empirical* mean and that $\sigma^2=E[(x_k-\mu)^2]$ where $\mu$ is the *theoretical* mean.) An indirect hint that the factor $\frac{N-1}N$ is needed is the $N=1$ case, where $x_1=\hat\mu$ hence $\hat\sigma^2=0$...

Comment: @Did Thank you for your help =)